# Pixlr - Transparent image with Text layer on top . Layer must be rasterized?

Tags: text, transparency, raster, pixlr

This is a noob question for sure, but I can't seem to find the answer. Using Pixlr Online in chrome I create a new transparent image and want to lay some text on top but keep getting the error that the **Layer must be rasterized**.  So I select the layer and Rasterize it, but still can't seem to add text. see this screencast.

[10 second Screen cast](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c2lvXGeUVM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tryed to do the same and it worked :/

In the dialog box do you selected the transparent option?

Maybe try to clear the cache and restart the browser.